# How do I correctly map a Python "list of lists" into an SQL table (built with SQLite3)?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have data coming out of an XML parser that contains instrument readings. Samples of the data are reproduced below:

```
cimReading = [['2012-08-15 10:05:13.101485', ['0x46'], ['0x32'], ['1.234'], ['5.678'], ['9.123'],
 ['4.567'], ['0x98'], ['0x97']], 
['2012-08-15 10:05:13.101979', ['0x47'], ['0x33'], ['8.901'], ['2.345'], ['6.789'], 
['0.123'], ['0x96'], ['0x95']]]
```

I'm trying to loop over the list items and put them away in a table, `cim76_dmt` that was previously defined in Python with `sqlite3`. Here is the code I'm using to try to do this:

```
for devList in cimReading:
    print devList
    cim76TabPopulate.execute('INSERT INTO cim76_dmt VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 
            devList)
BenchDB.commit()
cim76TabPopulate.close()
```

Here is the error message I receive upon execution:

```
['2012-08-15 10:40:21.110140', ['0x46'], ['0x32'], ['1.234'], ['5.678'], ['9.123'], ['4.567'], ['0x98'], ['0x97']]
EXCEPTION...
(<class 'sqlite3.InterfaceError'>, InterfaceError('Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.',), <traceback object at 0x1007a7518>)
```

So, I'm having a problem mapping a list item to a SQL table field. I think there should be a way to do this, but another possibility may be to tweak the XML parsing so I generate a single list of multiple strings for each record. I'd welcome any suggestions or advice on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that all the parameters after the first one are lists, not strings or integers. The part win the error message that is complaining about `unsupported type` is complaining about the data element `['0x46']`.

You need to massage your data a little bit more; you want to unpack `['0x46']` to `'0x46'`. This needs to be done to the other data elements in single length lists in your example data.

Comment: Hi Josef, Thanks for the reply. Yes, I thought the problem was tied to the data presentation as a 'list of lists'. I was looking for advice about whether I should re-write the XML parse code to deliver strings, or if there was a fast way to convert the list items to a sequence of strings. Which approach would you recommend?

Comment: Hm. Well, let the structure of the data suit its nature. If each element can only consist of 1 element then get rid of the list. So if your data is guaranteed to always only look like `[['2012-08-15 10:05:13.101485', ['0x46'] ...` and never like `[['2012-08-15 10:05:13.101485', ['0x46', 0x45] ...`. If you use the facilities in the way they were intended, then Everything Works Better(tm) so consider whether you might not also want an Integer field for values like `0x46` instead of the string representation.

Comment: It is a simple list, and I planned to leave the data in string format for storage in the SQL table, converting it only when I extract it to do calculations, etc. The numbers are coming "raw" from the instrument server in hex and floating point, and I add the timestamp when it is acquired via a function call. I think we both know the answer -- I need to go back to the XML parser and extract the data in this fashion.